# Missing libraries and other contains from gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm getting an error of **R** file and when I open **'build.Gradle'**. I got this inside the file and all libraries are gone.

I tried to clear cache and restart android studio.

Please help me out from this situation.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2011 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.gradle.api.artifacts;

/**
 * Unsuccessfully resolved dependency.
 */
public interface UnresolvedDependency {
    /**
     * The module selector of the dependency.
     *
     * @since 1.1-rc-1
     */
    ModuleVersionSelector getSelector();

    /**
     * the exception that is the cause of unresolved state
     */
    Throwable getProblem();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.enableBuildCache=false
```

to gradle properties.

or try this

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

Comment: but everything is removed form my gradle.